# SQL convert multi level xml with attribute into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I've the xml below which I'm trying to convert into a table.

```
declare @X xml = 
'<root>
<items>
    <item ItemID="100">
        <obj ObjID="0001" value="val1"/>
        <obj ObjID="0002" value="val2"/>
        <obj ObjID="0003" value="val3"/>
        <obj ObjID="0004" value="val4"/>
    </item>
    <item ItemID="200">
        <obj ObjID="0001" value="val1"/>
        <obj ObjID="0002" value="val2"/>
        <obj ObjID="0003" value="val3"/>
        <obj ObjID="0004" value="val4"/>
    </item>
</items>
</root>'
```

How can I transform the above xml into a table structure like below:

```
ItemID    ObjID
100       0001
100       0002
100       0003
100       0004
200       0001
200       0002
200       0003
200       0004
```

I've tried the statement below but it keeps on coming with NULL values for both (ItemID, ObjID) columns.

```
select 
    t.col.value('(/item/@ItemID)[1]', 'nvarchar(16)') as [ItemID],
    t.col.value('(/item/obj/@ObjID)[1]', 'nvarchar(16)') as [ObjID]
from 
@X.nodes('/root/items') as t(col)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Query

```
  SELECT 
    Tbl.Col.value('../@ItemID', 'nvarchar(16)') as [ItemID],  
    Tbl.Col.value('@ObjID', 'nvarchar(16)') as [ObjID]   
  FROM 
    @x.nodes('root/items/item/obj') Tbl(Col);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    i.col.value('@ItemID', 'nvarchar(16)') as [ItemID],
    o.col.value('@ObjID', 'nvarchar(16)') as [ObjID]     
from @X.nodes('/root/items/item') as i(col)
    outer apply i.col.nodes('obj') as o(col)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/24513)</kbd>**